# Open database of PCI-DSS violations

Tags: data-request, finance, security, crime

The [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) forces merchants who want to work with  Visa/MasterCard/etc to have a firewall, encrypt passwords, send card numbers over HTTPS, etc.

Is there a database of PCI-DSS violations, to which anyone can send reports?

I have thought about [Bugtraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugtraq) and [CVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures), but they are for software vulnerabilities, not for websites vulnerabilities.

*Context:

When trying to order a ticket from an airline's official website, I have randomly noticed that they send credit card numbers over HTTP. I tried contacting them but they don't seem to care.

That company is based in a non-democratic country that does not have anything like [ico.org.uk](http://ico.org.uk/).*

Comment: I found these: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17835/how-can-i-report-pci-dss-violations http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3219/is-there-a-way-for-a-consumer-to-report-pci-non-compliance

Comment: @JoeGermuska: Yes I have read these before posting my question. The conclusion of both is that there is no PCI-DSS-official website/database to report violations. That's why a community-built website/database is needed.

Comment: So then the answer is no?